# Magento 2: When registration.php is called?

Tags: magento2, module, custom, component

When we built/install new module it should have `registration.php` as per Magento Standard.

When we run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. Module will be installed.

How actually this command check for my custom module's `registration.php` & install it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For modules installed with composer, `registration.php` should be registered as autoload file in `composer.json`.

For local modules in "app" (which you seem to be referring to), there is [`app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php) which itself is registered as autoloader file and looks for the following paths:

```
$pathList[] = dirname(__DIR__) . '/code/*/*/cli_commands.php';
$pathList[] = dirname(__DIR__) . '/code/*/*/registration.php';
$pathList[] = dirname(__DIR__) . '/design/*/*/*/registration.php';
$pathList[] = dirname(__DIR__) . '/i18n/*/*/registration.php';
$pathList[] = dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/lib/internal/*/*/registration.php';
$pathList[] = dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/lib/internal/*/*/*/registration.php';
```

Comment: Understand. So when `NonComposerComponentRegistration.php` called? & What will be flow while executing upgrade command? It checks what first?

Comment: "which itself is registered as autoloader file" - this means, it is called via `vendor/autoload.php`, the autoloader generated by composer, on every request.

Comment: @AnkitShah when the autoloader is called so when app/bootstrap.php is called

Comment: @fschmengler Very Big Flow for Calling 1 to Another File Internally.